# What is the difference between built and SDK version of dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, onload

I have made a strange experience regarding `dojo/domReady!` and different versions (Built vs. SDK). The scripts are loaded in the following order: first the third party library (x3dom.js), then dojo and at last our own.

```
<!--  load x3dom -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../x3dom/dist/x3dom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../x3dom/dist/x3dom-full.js"></script>

<!-- load Dojo -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dojoConfig = {
        async: true,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        isDebug: false,
        baseUrl: "../dist/",
        packages: [
            { name: "dojo",  location: "dojo" },
            { name: "dijit", location: "dijit" },
            { name: "dojox", location: "dojox" }
        ]
    };
</script>

<script src="../dist/dojo.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/dijit.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/dojox.js"></script>
<script src="js/myCode.js"></script>
```

In our code we prepare the elements for X3DOM, but we need to wait until the DOM has been loaded completely. That is why we use `dojo/domReady!`:

```
require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(parser) {
        parser.parse().then(function() {
            console.log("DOM Loaded");
            // ... prepare stuff for x3dom
            x3dom.runtime.ready = function() { console.log('X3DOM ready'); }; // might never be called depending on the size of the document
        });
});
```

The built version of dojo somehow registers our custom function and executes it before any other code. However using the SDK version of Dojo showed, that the 3rd party code, due to some `window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);`, is being executed before our code and thus X3DOM fails to load its elements.

It also depends on the size of the document being loaded. If this is quite small, then the build version and the SDK version give the same result. If the document is quite large and a lot of parsing has to be done, then the before mentioned effect can be experienced.

What is the major difference between the built and SDK version of Dojo? Why do they behave completely different regarding `dojo/domReady!`?

Comment: I don't think the question is what the difference is between the SDK and built version. I think it's rather an asynchronous problem of your code trying to use X3DOM in Dojo when it's not loaded yet. The SDK version is not minified, so things will take longer before it's ready.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Is there anything I could do to improve this? Afaik X3DOM is not AMD compatible. But it would be great to use Dojo's require with it.